# onclick not working with html5

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

My code  is not working. I'm using the code mentioned below, I'm using text instead of image with this code.

```
<html> <head><script type="text/javascript">
 function playSound(el,soundfile) {
      if (el.mp3) {
          if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
          else el.mp3.pause();
      } else {
          el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
          el.mp3.play();
      }
  }</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="playSound(this, 'sliderBeatles/engine1/dil.mp3');">
                            <span id="dummy">
                            Play Sound<span></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are using seprated `onclick` event, when `href` will do trick for you. Use Below Code

```
<!doctype html>

<html> <head><script type="text/javascript">
 function playSound(el,soundfile) {debugger;
      if (el.mp3) {
          if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
          else el.mp3.pause();
      } else {
          el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
          el.mp3.play();
      }
  }</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript: playSound(this, 'sliderBeatles/engine1/dil.mp3');" >
                            <span id="dummy">
                            Play Sound<span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

further, If you want to use `onclick` and `href` both, try

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onClick='playSound(this, "sliderBeatles/engine1/dil.mp3");'>
```

Please Notice single quotes `'` for onclick event.
Thanks

Comment: for me, both worked when alone href worked and for single quotes too. any error in console???

Comment: I cleared cache also , i am using mozilla firefox, when i click on the play sound button nothing happened.

Comment: it seems like button and script might be in separate documents. Can you please confirm, if button or script is inside iframe??

Answer (score 0):

This example uses data-attributes and binds with jQuery's .on().

And maybe it's better to use a button element for this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function playSound(el,soundfile) {debugger;
  if (el.mp3) {
    if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
    else el.mp3.pause();
  } else {
    el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
    el.mp3.play();
  }
}

$('playSound').on('click', function() {
    playSound(this, $('playSound').data('song'));
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="playSound" data-song="sliderBeatles/engine1/dil.mp3">
   <span id="dummy">Play Sound<span>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate but I think you made a little mistake with onclick, I think that if you write it like `onClick` with the "C" on caps it will be taken as an attribute you defined.

have you tried writing `onclick="playSound(...)"` insted of `onClick="playSound(..)"` ?

I think that this could be the problem, who knows... maybe  :)

hope this helps!!!